# Once i Calculate two digit to output should be different then excel sheet in php

Tags: php, excel, date, math, time

Here I have to `decimal` number like `(1406354340,1406354341)`, now I apply some formula on this two number in excel sheet like following,assume that there is cell `c3` and `c2` and value of

```
c2 = 1406354340 and c3 = 1406354341   =(c3-c2)/86400
```

output is like 1.18203E-05 then I will be change format of cell to `[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM` to display `12:00:01 AM`

now onward I follow above format apply in php. please see following code

```
$unix_time1='1406354340'; $unix_time2='1406354341';

$timestamp = (((float)$unix_time2)-((float)$unix_time1))/86400;

echo "<br>".date('h:m:s A',strtotime($timestamp));
```

Output will be:
Once I display $timestamp `1.1574074074074E-5` time is `01:01:00 AM`

From php and Excel output is so far different why?

Please help me for solve this issue.

Comment: An MS Excel timestamp isn't a Unix timestamp, it's a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 on Mac versions of MS Excel), not a number of seconds since 1st January 1970

Comment: thank you share a feedback but i want ans as per excel sheet it's a right ans so how to got ?

Comment: What are the actual values of cells C2 and C3 in MS Excel? (without format masks applied).... or how are you reading your MS Excel spreadsheet in PHP? Is the library that you're using changing these values?

Comment: Or do you simply need to change your Excel formula to `=DATEDIF(C2, C3, 'D')`

Comment: The value of c2 and c3 is 1406354340 and  1406354341 respectively. ans will be 12:00:01 AM as per Excel

Comment: Still trying to guess exactly what you're doing here, and whether it has any meaning whatsoever.... but (just hazarding a guess) execute `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` immediately before you do `echo "<br>".date('h:m:s A',strtotime($timestamp));`

Comment: But just out of interest, what version of PHP are you running? I'm guessing between version 5.1.0 and 5.2.5

Comment: Current version of PHP `5.4.7` and If I am putting this `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` immediately before `echo "<br>".date('h:m:s A',strtotime($timestamp));` output will be `12:01:00` still it's wrong output. Right answer is `12:00:01 AM`.

Comment: Alright. Lets go back to basics, why are you doing that /86400? `1406354340` and `1406354341` are both unix timestamp values, so they're in seconds anyway, so what does dividing by `86400` actually achieve. What is `12:00:01 AM` supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you simply trying to work out the difference between the two values as hours/minutes/seconds? If so, __DON'T__ divide by 86400, because `1406354341-1406354340` gives you the difference in seconds

Comment: And the issue with `12:01:00 AM` and `12:00:01 AM` is because you're using `m` for minutes when you should be using `i` in your date format string; nor should you be converting your timestamp to a timestamp using strtotime() __because it already is a timestamp__

Comment: [This](http://3v4l.org/sbbN7) is what you should be doing

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you following code

```
    $unix_time1='1406354340'; $unix_time2='1406354341';

    $timestamp = (($unix_time2)-($unix_time1));

   echo date('h:i:s A',strtotime($timestamp));
```

this will return `12:00:01 AM`